# Evaluate Poker Hand (Python)

Tags: python

All I would to know is why I'm not able to rank the player's hand in this piece of code and how I can I use this to return the hand of the player with FAST API.

My intention is to

- shuffle the deck, deal a single hand to the player and evaluate that hand thereafter display the rank of the player as API response.

I can't figure out how to evaluate the hand because I'm getting an error that I don't seem to trace successfully.

```
class Hand(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the hand object
        super().__init__()
        self.hand = []

    # print the hand object as a string
    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([str(card) for card in self.hand])

    # function to draw (N) Cards from the deck

    def draw_cards(self, deck, num):
        for i in range(num):
            card = deck.deal()
            if card:
                self.hand.append(card)
            else:
                return False
        return True

class Evaluator:

    @staticmethod
    def is_cards_in_sequence(ranks):
        sorted_ranks = sorted(ranks)
        for i in range(len(sorted_ranks) - 1):
            if i == 0:
                if sorted_ranks[i] == 'A' and sorted_ranks[i + 1] == '10':
                    continue
            if sorted_ranks[i] != (sorted_ranks[i + 1] - 1):
                return False
            return True

    # function to return a count of each rank in the hand
    @staticmethod
    def get_count(ranks):
        return [ranks.count(c) for c in ranks]

    # get the rank of the hand
    def get_rank(self, hand):

        suits = [card.suit for card in hand]
        ranks = [card.rank for card in hand]

        if self.is_cards_in_sequence(ranks) and len(set(suits)) == 1:
            return 'Straight Flush'

        elif self.get_count(ranks) == 4:
            return 'Four of a Kind'

        elif self.get_count(ranks) == 3 and self.get_count(ranks) == 2:
            return 'Full House'

        elif len(set(suits)) == 1:
            return 'Flush'
        elif self.is_cards_in_sequence(ranks):
            return 'Straight'
        elif self.get_count(ranks) == 3:
            return 'Three of a Kind'
        elif len(set(self.get_count(ranks))) == 3:
            return 'Two Pair'
        elif len(set(self.get_count(ranks))) == 4:
            return 'One Pair'
        else:
            return 'High Card'


error :  
suits = [card.suit for card in hand]
TypeError: 'Hand' object is not iterable
```

Comment: what do you think the return from `self.get_counts` looks like and will it ever be `== 3` ? you could debug by adding some `print(something_helpful)` at various places in your code, to try and figure out why this might not be working ...

Comment: So what you intend to say is I should return something meaningful for each 'if' statement?

Comment: no what i intend to say is put a bunch of print statements in to help you debug what is going on .... and that self.get_counts returns a list ... so a list can never ==3 ...

Comment: I solved the error by making the hand object iterable. 
    ` def __iter__(self):
        if not self.hand:
            raiseExceptions
        else:
            return iter(self.hand)  `

Comment: i dont think it is fixed ... i dont think with this code there is any way you can get full house or 3 of a kind ... but glad to hear you are getting closer :)

Comment: yeah, you are right I'm not getting those. only getting Hig Cards and straight.